# Freeze content above a table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm building a web page using jQuery / Bootstrap 3 / Datatables, and I need to freeze (prevent from scrolling) all the content above my Datatables table (#dtWrapper or #datatables in the snippet below).
I've played a bit with position and float attributes but without success until now.

Could someone please shed some light on this mystery ?

Thks,
Bruno

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">...</nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-body">...</div>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">...</div>
          <div class="panel-body">...</div>
          <div class="panel-body">...</div>
          <div id="dtWrapper" class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div id="datatables" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">
    <!-- Datatables table here -->
                </div>       
              </div>       
            </div>       
          </div>       
        </div>       
      </div>       
    </div>       
  </div>       
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Fixed header extension to your project. Download from [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/) . Once you have added the extension you can proceed to initialize the datatable and setting fixed header as true.

```
$('#datatables').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true
} );
```

Comment: Thx for the advice, but this doesn't fulfill my need as I can still scroll the part above my table. I need to have everything above the table not scroll at all.